# Design-pattern for late-bound interfaces in C++03

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interface, crtp

There are situations you want to use a class as an implementation for an interface, but you cannot
modify code or encapsulate this class (e.g. derive from it). In other situations, you may want to
preempt such a situation.
//
Let's assume for the following examples, that we have the following "sealed" class, whereof we cannot
change code:

```
class my_sealed_class;
class my_lock 
{
    friend class my_sealed_class;
    my_lock() {}
    my_lock(my_lock const&) {}
};

class my_sealed_class : virtual my_lock
{
private:
    int x;

public:
    void set_x(int val) { x = val; }
    int  get_x() const  { return x; }
};
```

There are basically two kind of design-patterns you can choose from:
1.) Implementation as member object of the interface.

```
template<class implementation>
class my_interface0
{
private:
    implementation m_impl;

public:
    void set_x(int val) { m_impl.set_x(val); }
    int  get_x() const  { return m_impl.get_x(); }
};
```

Due to functionality of C++03 templates, this is pretty type-safe. Many compilers will inline the
actually called member function of 'implementation' - Unfortunately, not every compiler. In some
cases we must deal with unnecessary calls.

2.) Using CRTP pattern without deriving from base.

```
template<class derived>
class my_interface1
{
public:
    void set_x(int val) { reinterpret_cast<derived*>(this)->set_x(val); }
    int  get_x() const  { return reinterpret_cast<derived const*>(this)->get_x(); }
};
```

Yeah, I know: That isn't the normal way the CRTP pattern is used. Normally we would define something
like that:

```
template<class derived> class base { void foo() { static_cast<derived*>(this)->foo(); } };
class derived : base<derived>      { void foo() {} };
```

Unfortunately, we cannot do this. Remember, we cannot change code of our implementation class.
Let's think about what exactly is going using my_interface1 with my version of CRTP pattern. In
theory of the programming language C++03, it's safe to cast a derived-class pointer to one of his
base classes. On the other hand, it's not safe to cast in the opposite direction (from base to
derived) or to a totally different type. There is no guarantee that the memory object has reserved
as many bytes as needed for base and derived classes.
But, in practice, this doesn't belong to this example, because our interface doesn't contain any
member. Thus, it's size is 0 byte (please notice that operator new does allocate at least 1 byte, even
when the class is empty). In this case it's - practically - safe to cast any type-pointer to a
'my_interface1 pointer. The decisive advantage is, that alsmost every compiler will inline the calls to the actually called member function.

```
int main()
{
    // Not even worth to mention: That's safe.
    my_sealed_class msc;
    msc.set_x(1);

    // Safe, because 'my_interface0' instantiates 'my_sealed_class'.
    my_interface0<my_sealed_class> mi0;
    mi0.set_x(2);

    // Absolutely unsafe, because 'my_interface1' will access memory which wasn't allocated by it.
    my_interface1<my_sealed_class> mi1;
    mi1.set_x(3);

    // Safe, because 'my_interface1*' references an my_sealed_class object.
    my_interface1<my_sealed_class>* pmi1 = reinterpret_cast<my_interface1<my_sealed_class>*>(&msc);
    pmi1->set_x(4);

    return 0;
}
```

So, what do you think is best practice?
Best regards.

Comment: (2) is really awful. What's the benefit of doing this? Why would compilers inline (2) and not (1)? Wouldn't (1) be more efficiently optimized when the implementation class (my_sealed_class) has virtual methods?

Comment: Oh, virtual methods are the slowest possibility to implement this. Think about it and remember, you have to use vtable to call a function.

Comment: No i meant, *if* my-sealed_class has virtual methods (and cannot be modified), the compiler might be able to inline (1) (is it allowed to?) but not (2).

Comment: s/inline/avoid using the vtable/

Comment: Now I know what you mean, but I think this will happen only in absolutely rare situations, where you don't make much use of an base-class object (thus, the compiler will replace the calls).

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like option two has both undefined behavior *and* violates the strict aliasing rules, which may very well disable certain optimizations or break your code. Additionally anyone coming in and reading the code will almost certainly get very confused about its workings.

The first example is valid code, a standard pattern that will be understood by most programmers, and should be inlined by pretty much any compiler. I would definitely recommend this approach. Even in some strange world where the compiler is unable to inline the pass-through calls, only if profiling shows that the extra calls were a significant bottleneck would I consider some other approach to improve performance.

EDIT: To answer the final question of the original question: It would *never* be best practice to use option 2 over option 1. If there are performance problems with option 1 there are probably better ways to solve them than undefined behavior.

Comment: Just like I said before: If you want to inline your function calls (and you've got good reasons, why you need this), you should always prefer to use the CRTP pattern. If it's not necessary (due to performance issues), then you should prefer to use the pattern shown by the first example.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand, you cannot use inheritance (derive from `my_sealed_class`) because its methods are not declared virtual and you cannot change it. Did you try private inheritance?

In this case, I'd go with option (1) composition, because its simpler and easier to read and compilers optimize it pretty well. I also think its what the STL does.

(2) only *looks* faster, those reinterpret casts won't be as easy to optimize and the code is a bit hard to read.

Comment: Like I said: (2) will be inlined by almost every compiler, whereby you can hope for it will do the same for (1).